# Visual C++ wxWidgets app does only work on my PC

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I developed an app in visual studio using wxWidgets everything works fine on my machine. I tried to run my app on a different pc and i got errors like "ucrtbase.dll missing" etc. Then i tried to change to Multithreaded(/MT) mode and to changed debug to release mode but then i cant run the app on my pc because everything from wxWidgets gets red underline.

Comment: ucrtbase.dll is an OS component that gets distributed through Windows Update.  Make sure it got a chance to update this machine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simplify your life greatly ( and the life of your users! ) by statically linking to your libraries.

This is a big topic, but the first thing to do is to read up on how to build and link to the static wxWidgets libraries.

Give it a try and then ask individual questions when you hit problems.

Comment: Not everything can be statically linked - nor do you always want to do so. You are most likely always going to have to ship *some* dynamic libraries with your application if  it is something non-trivial, so you may as well learn how to do so up-front.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I disagree completely.  I have been shipping non trivial applications for many years and always use static linking for everything.  It is always worthwhile to avoid "DLL Hell"  If you expose clients to DLL Hell, you will lose them.

Comment: @ravenspoint Quite often, especially when using open source libraries in closed source applications, you don't really have the option of static linking if you intend to obey the license of the open source library. (This does not apply to wxWidgets, but many many others.)

Comment: @LauriNurmi Do not develop closed source applications.  They are full of bugs and have terrible quality issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ship the Visual Studio runtime libraries (aka Visual Studio redistributables) with your application. They are needed by all applications built by Visual Studio.
You also (of course) need to include any other libraries you may be using (like wxWidgets).

Comment: Thanks i also tried to copy all ddls with the exe but it did not work either

Comment: @Pyrex google for "visual studio redistributable" matching your VS version. MS has a nice MSI installer that you can download, include and install alongside your app.